# Setting page size in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

It is possible to set page size in ArcPy?

I'm looking for any tricky way to set the page size, using pure Python or ArcPy.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I believe MXDs must be pre-authored with the desired page sizes. At 10.1 the ability to query the page size was added, but not set it.

Sources:

- [Change Page Sizes in Atlas Using Python Script](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40712-Change-Page-Sizes-in-Atlas-Using-Python-Script)
- [What's new for automating map workflows in ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w00000022000000)